# How to fix 'The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, postman

I'm developing a REST service with Laravel to consume it from a mobile app. It works properly on local, but not on hosting. After several tries, I developed a basic example to test the POST method, but it returns the same error.

**api.php** file

```php
Route::post('/test', 'testController@test') ;
```

**testController.php** file

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class testController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function test(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json(['mensaje' => 'POST access successful']); 
    }
}
```

POST request is always returning the same error, and I am using POST on petition: **405 Method Not Allowed. The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST**.

[POSTMAN request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zikei.png)

I have investigated this topic and I  have read it could be due CORS. So, I have installed [spatie/laravel-cors](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors) with its default config, but POSTMAN is still showing the same error. Some help, please?

**SOLVED:**
Thanks all! Definitely, it was not a CORS problem. My hosting server makes a redirect by default, losing POST parameters in the way.

Comment: is your domain [https://midominio.com/](https://midominio.com/) actually working ?

Comment: It's not exactly this domain, but yes it's working. Furthermore, It has been tested with GET method and work properly.

Comment: so what is you url which works ?

Comment: My hosting server makes a redirect by default, losing POST parameters in the way. SO how did you solve it if you remmber?

Answer (score 10):

If you have come across this error while using POSTMAN, you need to go into the "Settings" part of your route's parameters and disable 'Automatically follow redirects'.

[image: automatically follow redirects, off]

Comment: It worked when I enabled instead of disable. But thank you for you help!

Comment: I ran into this issue again and once the redirects was disabled I got a 301 error -- using `valet secure` and making sure my local SSL was enabled overcame the issue.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes the problem arises when you have trailing froward slash.

For example:

```
https://somedomain.com/api/test/
```

Simply remove the trailing forward slash so the url will be

```
https://somedomain.com/api/test
```

Answer (score 4):

It's sometimes because you're using 'http' on an 'https'-based endpoint. Try replacing the http with https.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If your server force to use https it best to replace the http with https.
Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 3):

This is because of CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) is protected and you are not allow to call your api from other origin. To allow put below header setting to your routes in `api.php`

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use Postman the problem can be that you forgot to add the headers on your request : Accept -> application/json

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you call `/api/test`  because in api.php route file there is a prefix on routes